# MVC Razor MultiSelectList Getting/Setting SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, listbox, multi-select

I'm using [erichynds Multi Select Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) to create a nice style for my MultiSelectList.  But my issue (appears) to be unrelated.

I am trying to loop through each `DemographicQuestionFilter` question, list out the `DemographicResponseFilter` response and be able to get/post the selected items along with my `DemographicFilterViewModel` model.  The issue I am having is that when I set the filters for item-1 (index 0) in the list it works fine, when I set item-2 (index 1) it only works if item-1 is also set, if item-1 is not set then the `DemographicFilters` object is null.  I'm assuming I can switch up types, or that I'm missing something basic here.

How can I make it so that the list containing the selected items for n Question is not dependent n-1 also having a selected item?

Here are my ViewModel objects:

Parent:

```
public class DemographicFilterViewModel
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public List<DemographicQuestionFilter> DemographicFilters { get; set; }
}
```

Child:

```
public class DemographicQuestionFilter
{   
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public List<DemographicResponseFilter> Responses { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> selectListItems { get; set; }

    public List<int> SelectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

Grandchild:

```
public class DemographicResponseFilter
{
    public int ResponseID { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TaskID)
if (Model.DemographicFilters != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.DemographicFilters.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DemographicFilters[i].SelectedItems)
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.DemographicFilters[i].Question)
        <br />
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.DemographicFilters[i].SelectedItems, new MultiSelectList(Model.DemographicFilters[i].Responses, "ResponseID", "Response", Model.DemographicFilters[i].SelectedItems),  new { Multiple = "multiple" })
        <br />
        <br />
    }
}
```

Here is what is rendered to the screen (just so you can try to follow what I am doing):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1pK2.png

Edit: The issue is when the View posts back to the controller, the View displays correctly, but on HttpPost the values in [n]SelectedItems are dependent on [n-1]SelectedItems having a value,

If [i]SelectedItems is blank (nothing selected) then every [>i]SelectedItems is null, even when the values are correctly set in the HttpGet...

HTMLHelper Extension:

```
#region Usings

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Mvc;

#endregion

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString HiddenEnumerableFor<TModel, TEnumType>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TEnumType>>> expression)
        {
            return htmlHelper.Hidden(htmlHelper.NameFor(expression).ToHtmlString(),
                string.Join(",", expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model) ?? new TEnumType[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is an extension on what Vasanth Sundaralingam posted in his answer, that `HiddenFor` won't work with arrays.  I went ahead and created a function that behaves like a `hiddenFor` for enumerable properties.

```
@functions
{
    public MvcHtmlString HiddenEnumerableFor<TModel, TEnumType>(
        HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TEnumType>>> expression) 
    {

        return htmlHelper.Hidden(htmlHelper.NameFor(expression).ToHtmlString(),
            string.Join(",", expression.Compile().Invoke(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model) ?? new TEnumType[0]));
    }
}
```

Replace

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => filter.SelectedItems)
```

With

```
@HiddenEnumerableFor(Html, m => m.DemographicFilters[i].SelectedItems)
```

You could also convert this into an extension method by adding it to a static class, and adding `this` before the first parameter.  That way it would look like very similar to `HiddenFor`

```
@Html.HiddenEnumerableFor(m => m.DemographicFilters[i].SelectedItems)
```

Comment: I'll test your solution tomorrow, but there shouldn't be any nulls in the View.  The View gets the data correctly and displays correctly, it's the PostBack which posts back with missing values which are set in the view.  So if filter.SelectedItems has a value then filter.index -1.SelectedItems must have a value set (must have items selected).

Comment: Okay well my answer won't help you, post that information in your question because it was not clear.

Comment: @Html.HiddenEnumerableFor(m => m.DenographicFilders[i].SelectedItems): It says it can't find HiddenEnumerableFor (Autocomplete doesn't find it either). - I put my extension method class in to the question in case I missed something!

Answer (score 2):

HiddenFor cannot be used for ListBoxFor so here is the workaround I tried to fix the issue.

Replaced

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => filter.SelectedItems)
```

With

```
  @Html.Hidden(string.Format("DemographicFilters[{0}].SelectedItems", i), "-1")
```

Problem with this approach is that your DemographicFilters.SelectedItems will have an extra row -1 added to it, need to add code to exclude -1 row.

Comment: I'll try this in the morning.  I tried to create a list with a single "0" int in it as a different workaround (I removed the hidden field) but that didn't help.  I'll post back tomorrow once I've tried this :-)

Comment: Your solution worked, I just preferred to to do it in a @html.HiddenBlah way :)  Thanks!